# How long could the Sun power the Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, estimation, power, sun

With the energy emitted by the sun in 1 second, how long could everyone household on earth be powered?

Currently we obviously can't harvest 100% of the sun's energy emissions.

Comment: You might find interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere

Answer (score 1):

The total world energy consumption in 2018 was ~22,315 TWh ~ 8.0334 x 10<sup>19</sup> J [e.g., see https://www.iea.org/reports/electricity-information-overview].  For a 365 day year with 86,400 seconds per day, this would correspond to an average power consumption of ~2.547 x 10<sup>12</sup> W.

The [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) generates on the order of ~3.828 x 10<sup>26</sup> W of electromagnetic energy at its surface, which corresponds to ~1370 W m<sup>-2</sup> at the orbit of Earth.  We just divide the two numbers to get ~9.311 x 10<sup>9</sup> m<sup>2</sup> for an area we'd need to cover with solar panels (assuming 20% efficiency), or ~3595 mi<sup>2</sup> (~9311 km<sup>2</sup>).  That's a little less than two Delaware's in terms of area.  The [Mojave Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojave_Desert) in the southwestern United States has an aread of ~106,945 mi<sup>2</sup>, for reference.

> With the energy emitted by the sun in 1 second, how long could everyone household on earth be powered?

If we assume 20% efficiency in energy capture and use the numbers above, then that would correspond to ~3.005 x 10<sup>13</sup> seconds of energy or ~3.479 x 10<sup>8</sup> days or ~953,021 years.

Comment: This is insane. Thanks for calculating